# When I click on admin category menu , it redirects to admin login page prestashop 1.7.6

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I logged in to the PrestaShop admin and goes to the category menu but after some time it logged me out because of session/inactivity.
It redirects me to admin login page with redirect category controller and token.
And after again login, it always redirects me to the login page without any error.
But when I remove the redirect and token then it works fine and redirect to the dashboard.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me using `1.7.6.2`. I found out it was a webserver problem.

I changed my Centos Web panel "Nginx & Varnish & Apache" to "Nginx & Apache".
It fixed the problem in my case.

Maybe you could try this idea

Answer (score 0):

If you have a proxy service (like Cloudflare)
make sure to properly configure your webserver to receive the real visitor IP and not the proxy one as it might change during admin session,
otherwise you can disable IP checking from cookie in Prestashop from

**Advanced Parameters > Administration > Check the cookie's IP address**
.